# I have some problems with def save_hyperparameters(self, ignore=[]): code in d2l book

Tags: python-3.x, d2l

This segment code define a class HyperParameters with function save_hpyerparameters

```
class HyperParameters:  #@save
    """The base class of hyperparameters."""
    def save_hyperparameters(self, ignore=[]):
        raise NotImplemented
```

And this segment implement a class B with init function. But why the attribute 'c' is ignored after the `save_hpyerparameters` function is called? The function does nothing but only just raise a NotImplemented exception!

```
# Call the fully implemented HyperParameters class saved in d2l
class B(d2l.HyperParameters):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.save_hyperparameters(ignore=['c']) #??? why parameter c is ignored?
        # self.save_hyperparameters(ignore=[])
        print('self.a =', self.a, 'self.b =', self.b)
        print('There is no self.c =', not hasattr(self, 'c'))

b = B(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

This is the result printed on screen.

```
self.a = 1 self.b = 2
There is no self.c = True
```

I want to know why the parameter c is ignored.

Comment: The answer probably lies in code you didn't show us, probably involving a method override. (It's probably all explained in a part of the book you skipped.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's just two code segments indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I think I should have found the answer: The B class extends from d2l.HyperParameters not the HyperParameters class shown above.